# bash script to replace server short names in a file with fqdn

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, awk, scripting

I have a rather large config file that has server short names in it like this:

```
[host 1]
host = server1

[host 2]
host = server2

[host 3]
host = server3
```

I need to replace all the server short names with the fq long names that will be outputted from a bash script I've already written, lookup.sh. Can I work some sed or awk magic to accomplish this task?

Comment: what have you tried to do? using sed is of course possible, but let us know what you tried to do before.

Comment: How do you call lookup.sh? `lookup.sh <hostname>`?

Comment: "lookup.sh server1" will output server1.server.domain.com, of course this function could be added to the main search and replace script instead of calling it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question implied the use of `sed` or `awk`, but you didn't explicitly rule out `perl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>)
{
    if (/^host = (.+)/) {
        print "host = " . `./lookup.sh $1`;
    }
    else { 
        print;
    }
}
```

Upon further reflection, the same could be done in `awk` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

INFILE=$1

awk 'BEGIN { FS = " = " } ; {
        if ($1 == "host") {
                "'"./lookup.sh "'" $2 | getline fqdn
                $2 = "="; $3 = fqdn
        }
        print
}' $INFILE
```

Comment: Hah, I was asking for it... Yeah perl will work, thank you. Personally I try to do everything in bash but you can't argue with results. Thanks again, just tested and it does what I need.

Comment: Now if someone can tell me how to do the above in bash :)

Comment: @JoeMama I just included a pure bash/awk solution in the answer.

Comment: Of course, that's a pure bash/awk solution in the same sense that the perl script is a  pure bash/perl solution.  `awk` is no more a part of "pure" sh or bash than `perl` is, it's just another external (to sh/bash) scripting language.